# Prompt user to save or open in openXML

Tags: openxml-sdk

I'm using OpenXml sdk 2 to create a spreadsheet. How do I prompt the user to choose a save location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open XML SDK 2.0 is used in creating the underlying XML that makes up an Excel, Word, or PowerPoint file.  The functionality you are seeking is part of the Excel program and is not achievable through XML.

If you are sending the file back to the user to be downloaded they can choose where to save it from there.

Comment: So how might they do that. I was thinking of saving the file to the server, then streaming it to the client. Again, it's how I go about implementing that.

Comment: @hoakey - If you stream it to the client they will get the download prompt from the browser where they can then choose where they want to save the file. That is your best bet and less code you have to worry about.

Comment: That sounds positive. Where do I need to look to achieve this?

Comment: @hoakey - This post should give you some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671702/open-xml-replace-text-from-word-file-and-return-memory-stream-using-mvc