# Error using OpenXML to read a .docx file from a memorystream to a WordprocessingDocument to a string and back

Tags: asp.net-core, openxml, docx, memorystream

I have an existing library that I can use to receive a docx file and return it. The software is .Net Core hosted in a Linux Docker container.

It's very limited in scope though and I need to perform some actions it can't do. As these are straightforward I thought I would use OpenXML, and for my proof of concept all I need to do is to read a docx as a memorystream, replace some text, turn it back into a memorystream and return it.

However the docx that gets returned is unreadable. I've commented out the text replacement below to eliminate that, and if I comment out the call to the method below then the docx can be read so I'm sure the issue is in this method.

Presumably I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here but after a few hours googling and playing around with the code I am not sure how to correct this; any ideas what I have wrong?

Thanks for the help

```
private MemoryStream SearchAndReplace(MemoryStream mem)
{
    mem.Position = 0;

    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
    {
        string docText = null;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream());
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        //Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
        //docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");


        MemoryStream newMem = new MemoryStream();
        newMem.Position = 0;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newMem);
        sw.Write(docText);

        return newMem;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need set breakpoint and debug to see `docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");` with xml visualizer.Check `Hello world!` if it is in the same line in xml file.If it is in the same line,you could search for it but the document would be corrupted.If it is not in the same line,you could not search for it.More details you could refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010906/11398810

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your real requirement is to search and replace text in a `WordprocessingDocument`, you should have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303646/open-xml-find-and-replace-multiple-placeholders-in-document-template/59328568#59328568).

The following unit test shows how you can make your approach work if the use case really demands that you read a string from a part, "massage" the string, and write the changed string back to the part. It also shows one of the shortcomings of any other approach than the one described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303646/open-xml-find-and-replace-multiple-placeholders-in-document-template/59328568#59328568) already mentioned above, e.g., by demonstrating that the string `"Hello world!"` will not be found in this way if it is split across `w:r` elements.

```cs
[Fact]
public void CanSearchAndReplaceStringInOpenXmlPartAlthoughThisIsNotTheWayToSearchAndReplaceText()
{
    // Arrange.
    using var docxStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(docxStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        MainDocumentPart part = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
        var p1 = new Paragraph(
            new Run(
                new Text("Hello world!")));

        var p2 = new Paragraph(
            new Run(
                new Text("Hello ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }),
            new Run(
                new Text("world!")));

        part.Document = new Document(new Body(p1, p2));

        Assert.Equal("Hello world!", p1.InnerText);
        Assert.Equal("Hello world!", p2.InnerText);
    }

    // Act.
    SearchAndReplace(docxStream);

    // Assert.
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docxStream, false))
    {
        MainDocumentPart part = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart;
        Paragraph p1 = part.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>().First();
        Paragraph p2 = part.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>().Last();

        Assert.Equal("Hi Everyone!", p1.InnerText);
        Assert.Equal("Hello world!", p2.InnerText);
    }
}

private static void SearchAndReplace(MemoryStream docxStream)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docxStream, true))
    {
        // If you wanted to read the part's contents as text, this is how you
        // would do it.
        string partText = ReadPartText(wordDocument.MainDocumentPart);

        // Note that this is not the way in which you should search and replace
        // text in Open XML documents. The text might be split across multiple
        // w:r elements, so you would not find the text in that case.
        var regex = new Regex("Hello world!");
        partText = regex.Replace(partText, "Hi Everyone!");

        // If you wanted to write changed text back to the part, this is how
        // you would do it.
        WritePartText(wordDocument.MainDocumentPart, partText);
    }

    docxStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}

private static string ReadPartText(OpenXmlPart part)
{
    using Stream partStream = part.GetStream(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
    using var sr = new StreamReader(partStream);
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}

private static void WritePartText(OpenXmlPart part, string text)
{
    using Stream partStream = part.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using var sw = new StreamWriter(partStream);
    sw.Write(text);
}
```